# Prevent CKEditor allowedContent from removing color button

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm building an editable text area with CKEditor v4.

When I set `allwedContent`, the color buttons disappear. What value works with them? (Or generally how to find proper values?) I'd like to use the config to prevent unexpected elements.

Here are the code:

```html
<textarea id="editor1"></textarea>
<textarea id="editor2"></textarea>
```

```js
console.log("CKEditor", CKEDITOR.version);

// the buttons works, but need to avoid some unwanted elements
CKEDITOR.replace("editor1", {
});

// set all HTML elements I remember
// With this, the color buttons don't appear
CKEDITOR.replace("editor2", {
  allowedContent: "a abbr acronym address applet area article aside audio b base bdi bdo bgsound big blink blockquote body br button canvas caption center cite code col colgroup content data datalist dd del details dfn dialog dir div dl dt em embed fieldset figcaption figure font footer form frame frameset h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 head header hr html i iframe image img input ins kbd keygen label legend li link main map mark marquee math menu menuitem meta meter nav nobr noembed noframes noscript object ol optgroup option output p param picture plaintext portal pre progress q rb rp rt rtc ruby s samp script section select shadow slot small source spacer span strike strong style sub summary sup svg table tbody td template textarea tfoot th thead time title tr track tt u ul var video wbr xmp",
});
```

[image]

And my `ckeditor/build-config.js` so that you can get the same package from [the builder](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder).

```js
/**
 * @license Copyright (c) 2003-2022, CKSource Holding sp. z o.o. All rights reserved.
 * For licensing, see LICENSE.md or https://ckeditor.com/legal/ckeditor-oss-license/
 */

/**
 * This file was added automatically by CKEditor builder.
 * You may re-use it at any time to build CKEditor again.
 *
 * If you would like to build CKEditor online again
 * (for example to upgrade), visit one the following links:
 *
 * (1) https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder
 *     Visit online builder to build CKEditor from scratch.
 *
 * (2) https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder/457de9399dbfa59f62ba046d45e91240
 *     Visit online builder to build CKEditor, starting with the same setup as before.
 *
 * (3) https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder/download/457de9399dbfa59f62ba046d45e91240
 *     Straight download link to the latest version of CKEditor (Optimized) with the same setup as before.
 *
 * NOTE:
 *    This file is not used by CKEditor, you may remove it.
 *    Changing this file will not change your CKEditor configuration.
 */

var CKBUILDER_CONFIG = {
    skin: 'moono-lisa',
    preset: 'standard',
    ignore: [
        '.DS_Store',
        '.bender',
        '.editorconfig',
        '.gitattributes',
        '.gitignore',
        '.idea',
        '.jscsrc',
        '.jshintignore',
        '.jshintrc',
        '.mailmap',
        '.npm',
        '.nvmrc',
        '.travis.yml',
        'bender-err.log',
        'bender-out.log',
        'bender.ci.js',
        'bender.js',
        'dev',
        'gruntfile.js',
        'less',
        'node_modules',
        'package-lock.json',
        'package.json',
        'tests'
    ],
    plugins : {
        'basicstyles' : 1,
        'colorbutton' : 1,
        'entities' : 1,
        'floatingspace' : 1,
        'removeformat' : 1,
        'sharedspace' : 1,
        'specialchar' : 1,
        'tab' : 1,
        'toolbar' : 1,
        'wysiwygarea' : 1
    },
    languages : {
        'en' : 1
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`allowedContent: "span{color,background-color}"` worked.

I found it in `ckeditor/plugins/colorbutton/plugin.js` in v4 source code. (If you're trying to download from the builder, select "Source".) There is an [`editor.ui.add()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_ui.html#method-add) call with the `allowedContent` config. Its value is not string but an object though, you can read it.